# Rudin, def. 4.1 (Principles of Mathematical Analysis)

Tags: functions

- Why in this definition in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* Rudin takes a subset  $E \subset X$ and not the whole metric space $X$ in which define the function $f$? [image: def. 4.1]
- Why in the following you can consider a function defined on $X$? [image: theorem 4.8]

Is the reason that he has to introduce a point $p \in E'$?

Comment: If you give the definition and the theorem you might get more answers. Not everyone has the book readily at hand.

Comment: Since I have left my copy of Rudin on the bedside cabinet, can you add the definitions / theorem to your question?

Comment: Sure! One moment

Answer (score 1):

$f$ need not be defined on all of $X$. It may only be defined on a subset, denoted $E$. In particular, this section is concerned with continuity, so $E$ for example could be the set on which $f$ is continuous.

For example, consider the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ on the metric space $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$. Then since $f$ is not defined at $x = 0$, our subset could be $E = \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$, and $f$ would be considered continuous on $E$.

Comment: I was thinking this, but I wondered: ok, you could only have that the domain of f is a subset of X. But why introduce X? Why don't start the definition with E? I didn't really see the reason

Answer (score 1):

Why would you have the definition of the operator "limit of a function in a point" be valid only for function defined on a entire metric space and not also for functions defined on a subset of its (question 1). Note also that the point where the limit can be computed must be a limit point (in the sense of the topology of the containing metric space) of the domain of the function so it may not belong to such a domain (question 2). These two questions are the reason why the containing metric space is introduced.

Comment: what are you mean with "entire metric space"? We aren't told what set is $X$, it could be as "strange" as you want set. It could be $Q \cap [0,1]$ and $E=\mathbb{Q} \cap [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ what is the problem with evaluating limit in E?

Comment: Indeed we are told that $X$ is a metric space.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main motivations for introducing limits is to define the derivative:
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.
$$
The function we are taking a limit of here is not defined at $0$.

We often find ourselves working with functions that are only defined on a subset of whatever space we're working in.